# Example of WCF, Unity, EntLib5, Linq-to-SQL with TDD and PI

Tags: c#, wcf, tdd, unity-container, enterprise-library

I am trying to develop a .NET 3.5 service application that uses:

- WCF for the service layer
- Business object layer to encapsulate our business logic (and isolate the service and data access layers)
- Linq-to-SQL for the data access technology
- Unity for dependency injection
- Enterprise Library 5 with the following:

  - Validation Application Block
  - Exception Handling Application Block
  - Logging Application Block

We are also looking to follow TDD and want persistence ignorance (PI) as we may be changing data access technologies to either NHibernate or EF when we upgrade to .NET 4.0 later in the year and we want to minimize the impact such a change will have by isolating it to just the data access layer.

I have been working with the application for a little over a week now and have quite a bit of it working.  I have yet to get the EHAB or LAB implemented successfully, validation is only partly implemented and PI is non-POCO based because we are required to support the designer (as opposed to using XML mapping).  We are using the repository pattern with interfaces for PI.

Can anyone point me to some quality (real-world) example solutions using these technologies together?  That's probably the best way to address my questions and concerns because the articles I've referenced thus far only touch on one or two aspects of my solution and things aren't working exactly the same as they describe when I wire all of this together.

Comment: +1 Interesting question. I hope you get some good answers.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of what you mean by *things aren't working exactly the same as they describe when I wire all of this together*

Comment: The Silverlight Cookbook shows and interesting architecture with a WCF service using Unity, EntLib, NHibernate, and using commands and handlers to process the business logic: http://silverlightcookbook.codeplex.com/

Comment: I can but I am looking for examples and best-practices how to create an application using these technologies and frameworks so I don't want to get bogged down on the specifics of what I've tried or not.  I can tell you that I've been unable to get WCF and the EHAB working together.  But, again, my question goes beyond that single aspect and I'm interested in the larger picture as that may have as much to do with my problems as a mistake in a single line of code.

Comment: This question is really too broad to get good answers from. I recommend you ask a larger number of smaller questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking through p&p hands-on labs:
[download sample solutions and instructions](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4f8cd377-5522-4f45-a024-44a6ca5111ec&displaylang=en)

These are pretty easy to work through, giving you guidance and usage patterns.